# Read 512 bytes from serialport then save to .bin

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

Im trying to read 512 bytes from serial then write it to the .bin file.

```
Dim bufferLength As Int16 = 512
Private Sub readserial()

    Dim buffer(bufferLength - 1) As Byte

    SerialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
    Using vFs As New FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\myfile.bin", FileMode.Append) 'save

        vFs.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
    End Using

End Sub
```

Jim's code

```
  Dim bufferLength As Integer = 512
Dim buffer(bufferLength - 1) As Byte
Private Sub serialport1_datareceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    If (SerialPort1.IsOpen) Then

        Do While SerialPort1.BytesToRead > 0

            Try



                SerialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
            Catch
            End Try

        Loop
        Using vFs As New FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\myfile.bin", FileMode.Append) 'save

            vFs.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that `.bin` shows me wrong data. It shows last byte as first byte in file then all zeros till the end of the file. Maybe I'm wrongly reading data or I don't know, any help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you want to append the data to an existing file rather than overwriting it or creating a new file? Also, you should check the value returned by `SerialPort1.Read`. There's no guarantee that the number of `Bytes` read is the maximum number that you specified.

Comment: Hello Jim, yes im sure, am deleting the file every time before read the buffer. Btw i found your code that im using now(edited above). But it doesnt solve the problem

Comment: It's a bit silly to delete a file and then create a `FileStream` to append to.  Just create a `FileStream` to overwrite and then it will work as intended regardless of whether a file already exists or not. As for that code, it doesn't look like anything I would endorse, so your editing probably needs some work. You still aren't using the value returned by `Read`.